# Linear Solution of Array Duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

Given an array = [3, 5, 8, 8]. I'm trying to figure out why my duplicate checker array is not returning True on the second 8. However, when I set array = [3, 8, 8, 8], the function returns True, but all my values are still set to None. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def Duplicates(arr):
    size = max(arr) + 1
    existingNumbers = [None] * size
    print(existingNumbers)
    for i in range(0, len(arr) -1):
        k = arr[i]
        if existingNumbers[k] == 1:
            return True
        else:
            existingNumbers[k] = 1
    print(existingNumbers)
    return False
```

```
arr = [3, 5 ,8, 8]
print(Duplicates(arr))
```

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) will be excluded from the number sequence, i.e. you don't have to subtract 1. Change

```
for i in range(0, len(arr) -1):
```

to

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
```

That being said, using indices is **not** the Pythonic way to iterate over a list. This is a better method:

```
for k in arr:
    if existingNumbers[k] == 1:
    ...
```

Update: Also note that you can simply use a `set` to remove duplicates from a list, then compare lengths to see if they match. This allows us to reduce your function to a single line:

```
def Duplicates(arr):
    return len(set(arr)) != len(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize what I was getting confused on. The second print(existingNumbers) for debugging was printing out the old array because of it's positioning. That tripped me up.

Comment: @Yuta You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it if it helped.